# How to add error highlights for Importing Unknown Packages or Modules in Monaco Editor for newly registered Language Java?

Tags: java, monaco-editor, monaco-languageserver

Currently we are integrating Java Language Server to Monaco Editor. There when I am trying  to import unknown modules or packages it is not throwing warning or errors.[image: No Error for Unknown Package]. Tried using Tokenizer but didn't worked out.

When I am importing any unknown package or error I want error some thing red lines below the package name. Similar to how we will get for typescript. I want to know how to add these type to monaco editor for a new language that we are registering.[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you did the semantic validation send diagnostics back, which your extension can use to add such information. For example:

```js
   /**
     * Convert diagnostic information for the given file to show in vscode.
     *
     * @param document The document for which this should happen.
     */
    private processDiagnostic = (document: TextDocument) => {
        const diagnostics = [];
        const entries = this.backend.getDiagnostics(document.fileName);
        for (const entry of entries) {
            const startRow = entry.range.start.row === 0 ? 0 : entry.range.start.row - 1;
            const endRow = entry.range.end.row === 0 ? 0 : entry.range.end.row - 1;
            const range = new Range(startRow, entry.range.start.column, endRow, entry.range.end.column);
            const diagnostic = new Diagnostic(range, entry.message, ExtensionHost.diagnosticTypeMap.get(entry.type));
            diagnostics.push(diagnostic);
        }
        this.diagnosticCollection.set(document.uri, diagnostics);
    };
```

(from my extension [antlr4-vscode](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/ExtensionHost.ts#L342)).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to provide some logic of detecting unknown imported packages.

Then, to underline errors, check corrrsponding page on [Monaco editor playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.36.1#example-extending-language-services-model-markers-example) or use this code:

```js
     monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(window.editor.getModel(), 'owner', [
            {
                message: "import not found",
                severity: monaco.MarkerSeverity.Error,
                startLineNumber: 0,
                startColumn: 0,
                endLineNumber: 0,
                endColumn: 2,
            },
        ]);
```

(change startLineNumber and other range arguments according to highlighted code piece).